# Javascript changes to match the pattern

Tags: javascript, html

I've the below code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #error
            {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            function showpay() {
                if ((document.calc.loan.value == null || document.calc.loan.value.length == 0) ||
                    (document.calc.months.value == null || document.calc.months.value.length == 0) ||
                    (document.calc.rate.value == null || document.calc.rate.value.length == 0)) {
                    document.calc.pay.value = "Incomplete data";
                }
                else {
                    var princ = document.calc.loan.value;
                    var term = document.calc.months.value;
                    var intr = document.calc.rate.value / 1200;
                    document.calc.pay.value = princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + intr), term)));
                }
            }

            function isNumberKey(evt) {
                var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
                if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                {
                    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'inline';
                    document.getElementById('error').style.color = 'red';
                    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'OOPs! Only digits allowed.';

                } else {
                    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
                    return true;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="calc">
            <p>
            <center>
                <table width="200" border="1">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                            <th scope="col">Data Entry</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Principle</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="loan" id="loan" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                            </td><span id="error"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Interest</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                        </td><span id="error"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tenure</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="months" id="months" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
                        </td><span id="error"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>EMI</td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="textfield4" type="text" id="pay" readonly></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick='showpay()'/></td>
                        <td><input type=reset value=Reset></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <font size=1>Enter only numeric values (no commas), using decimal points
                where needed.<br>
                Non-numeric values will cause errors.</font>
            </center>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

here i'm facing 2 problems,

1. The error i'm getting is not automatically fading.
2. the textboxes are accepting alphabets, where in i want only numbers and decimals as input. Also it is accepting othere special characters, only `.` should be accepted.
3. I want to restrict the textboxes only to accept numbers and `.`(decimal numbers).

please let me know how can i achieve these.

Thanks

Comment: create an INCLUSION list rather than exclusion through a switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fix the check of the `keypress`, but you need to change the `id` of the items so that you do not have multiple error `id`s. That is invalid HTML, which is probably why its not working as you expect.

```
function isNumberKey(e) {
    var charCode = (e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode),
        valid;

    switch(charCode){
        case 96:
        case 97:
        case 98:
        case 99:
        case 100:
        case 101:
        case 102:
        case 103:
        case 104:
        case 105:
        case 190:
            valid = true;
            break;
        default:
            valid = false;
            break;
    }

    if(valid){
        // remove the error
    } else {
        // add the error
    }

    return valid;
}
```

This will at least limit the characters you want to accept, as it creates an inclusion list of numeric (0-9) characters plus the period character.

Comment: Why a switch? `if(charCode >=96 && charCode <= 190) { valid = true; }`

Comment: because you just allowed all characters between 106 and 190 to be valid as well.

Comment: Sorry, `if((charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105) || charCode == 190) { valid = true; }`. Alternatively, if you really want to use a switch, you can get rid of the `valid = true;` and `break;` in everything above 190

Comment: Agreed, I whipped that up in 30 seconds with a lot of copy / paste, I can eliminate the repetition. Out of curiosity, though, is there a reason you are *against* the switch so vehemently? I don't have the time to run a jsPerf, but I feel confident it would be faster than the `if` statement you offered, with the `&&` checker combined with an `||`.

Comment: The switch statement is more verbose and less readable, in my opinion. Who cares if it's faster? How often do you plan on doing this?

Comment: More verbose - true, less readable - your opinion. Your `if` statement is more concise but less transaprent, imo. And "who cares if it's faster"? Putting aside how very, very sad it is that you even ask that question (are you a WordPress "developer" or something?), "how often do you plan on doing this" ... he was running this function on **every keypress**. So probably a friggin lot.

Comment: It happens *once* on every key press. It will not in either case provide a material difference in user experience, is my point, so that's why you should not worry about if it's faster in this case. Premature optimization is the root of all evil, as they say. Unless you have a specific scenario where performance is a problem, and you've done performance testing that shows this is a problem, do not worry about optimization. Make readability and maintainability your primary concern.

Comment: @ColinDeClue - I am not worried about optimization, nor am i worried about readability, because while I consider my method the superior version of both, I also realize how immensely trivial it is. Not sure why you are so strongly compelled to issue directives on coding methodology for such a subjective thing. Perhaps if you felt you had that much better of an answer, you could have provided an answer instead of peck at mine.

Comment: Hi @PlantTheIdea, your code is accepting the characters not the numbers, also the error message i typed is not displayed

Comment: @user3872094 - my code accepts the `keyCode` that the person types, and those `keyCode`s are for the numbers (0-9) as well as the decimal. Also, as made clear at the beginning of my post, your error message was not showing correctly because you were using multiple instances of IDs that were the same, which is invalid HTML. You need to have valid HTML, first, then create code that gets that sets the correct message for the correct box. My answer was to help you on your way, not solve all of your problems, because there are many in this code.